# JxMaps Error in JavaFX (JxBrowser Popup not closing)

Tags: java, javafx, jxbrowser, jxmaps

I am using the JxMaps class (with JavaFX), but there seems to be a massive issue - it must be in the original class, as it also happens with the examples provided by JxMaps...

So this is the problem:
For sake of explanation, let us use the "JavaFXExample.java" provided.

Click anything that will cause the JxBrowser Popup to show (such as the google logo in the bottom left hand corner or any POI... or streetview...

Now try close the popup: The program lags out and/or crashes.

This problem basically renders my project useless, as the user may click it and the program will freeze.

Any possible solutions?

---

#### Solved

Thanks to [Vitaly Eremenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6251714/vitaly-eremenko) for the prompt response, this issue has been resolved in version 1.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for issue reporting.

We've figured out cause of this issue and fixed it. Updated version you can download from official JxMaps site: [www.teamdev.com/jxmaps](http://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps).

Regards,
Vitaly.

Comment: Oh my word this is absolutely amazing! Thank you so much! Great support :)

Comment: Also, is there a way to determine current location within JxMaps? :) Without using IP geolocation? Using a google API withing JxMaps maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately, current version don't have this functionality. Now, we are investigating possibility to add it to one of next versions of JxMaps.